# How to use star (*) within an ansible interactive command

Tags: bash, ansible

I want to execute the following command using eval within an ansible interactive command, and a star character:

```
eval $(echo "ansible -i inventory_file allservers -m shell -a 'grep -h "$DAILYDATE " /route/to/logfiles/folder0*/logfile.log | head -1 '")
```

where $DAILYDATE changes every day, with format "2021-05-25" (that's the reason for using "eval" encapsulating the command).

The problem is that the wildcard character (the star *) is interpreted only once, and then used in every server with the same value, where it should be 1,2,3 etc.

```
server1 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
2021-05-25 00:01:10.042  INFO 100003 --- blabla

server2 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
grep: /route/to/logfiles/folder01/logfile.log: No such file or directory

server3 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
grep: /route/to/logfiles/folder01/logfile.log: No such file or directory
```

Any way to use the wildcard in this case?

Comment: I can't reproduce the command since I don't have ansible or your catalogues, consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.
However, have you tried quoting the asterisk character? For example ```\*``` or ```$'*'```

Comment: `eval $(echo "/bin/ls")` is equivalent to `eval "/bin/ls"`.  No need to `$( )` the command.